# What does “never” modify in “I am never late”?

Tags: adverbs, parts-of-speech, parsing

I need help with the sentence:

> I am never late.

What does the adverb “never” modify in that sentence? Does it modify the verb to be or does it modify the adjective?

Comment: A somewhat philosophical question: what's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this site](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Adverbs-of-Frequency.htm) "never" is here modifying the adjective.

> Adverbs of frequency can also modify adjectives, in which case they come after the verb be. This is because be is a linking verb (not a main verb), and the adverbs modify the predicative adjective(s) associated with it.
> For example, compare how the adverb of frequency always is used with the main verb have and the linking verb be in the following examples:
>
> “I **always** *have* lunch at one o’clock.”
>
> “I *am* **always** late for work.”
>
> In the first sentence, always is modifying the verb have, whereas in the second sentence, it is modifying the adjective late.

Comment: But consider this: "I never sleep."  Here, *never* clearly can't be modifying the adjective, because there isn't one.  So does adding an adjective change what *never* refers to?  It's a philosophical question.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with @Showsni

"Late" is not being modified by always, "am" is.  The degree to which you are late is in no way altered by "always".  Compare this with "I am very late".  "Very" modifies late.

If you can move the adverb before the first verb and it doesn't change the meaning, then it is modifying the first verb, otherwise it is modifying the second.

> I am very late

This obviously makes no sense if you move "very" before "am", so very is modifying late

> I am really late

This sentence changes meaning if you move "really" before "am", and "really" goes from meaning "very" to "in actuality"/"truthfully"